# Vector Push_back

Tags: c++, vector, push-back, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Empty check with string split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136923/empty-check-with-string-split)

I split the below string with '&' and saved it in a vector

```
const vector<string> vec = split("f0=fname0&l0=lname0&f1=fname1&l1=lname1&f2=fname2&l2=lname2&f3=&l3=","&");
```

Now i'm again splitting the split strings with '=' Using the below code.

```
vector<string> vec1;
for (std::vector<std::string>::size_type a = 0; a < vec.size(); ++a)
{
     vec1=split(vec.at(a),"=");

}
```

At last I'm getting only the last item of the vector 'vec' to 'vec1'. every time my vec1 pointer refreshing. But i want to add splitted string in last position of the vec1. 
How can i do this ?

Comment: What is this `split` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assign to `vec1` every time in the loop, so it will only contain the last pair. Instead you should *append* to `vec1`. This is done simplest with the [`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) function:

```
vector<string> vec1;
for (std::vector<std::string>::size_type a = 0; a < vec.size(); ++a)
{
    vector<string> tmp = split(vec.at(a),"=");
    vec1.insert(vec1.end(), tmp.begin(), tmp.end());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand what a vector is?
It does not make alot of sence, to split the string and put it into one vector "space" alltogether again (you could have just kept the string then)

I guess you are using boost's split() function.. then just skip the for loop and just call

```
const vector<string> vec = split("f0=fname0&l0=lname0&f1=fname1&l1=lname1&f2=fname2&l2=lname2&f3=&l3=","&");

for( int i = 0; i <= vec.size(); i++){
cout << i << "#: " << vec.at(i) << endl;
}
```

to see the vectors contents (at index)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are assigning to `vec1` instead of appending. You are replacing contents generated previously and ending up with result of last iteration (you could fix it by using `vec1.push_back()`).

So, you want to get a vector of strings with parameters, but how you gonna determine which value belongs to which parameter. IMO, you better use `std::map`:

```c++
using std::string;
using std::vector;
using std::map;

vector<stirng> vec = split("f0=fname0&l0=lname0&f1=fname1&l1=lname1&f2=fname2&l2=lname2&f3=&l3=","&");

map<string, string> params;

for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it) {
    vector<string> p = split(*it, "=");
    params.insert(p[0], p[1]);
}
```

Now you will have list of keys with it's values inside of `params`, so you will be able to `params["f0"]`.